# AngularJS ng-disabled button if input $pristine - doesn't work if all text highlighted and deleted

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I've used ng-disabled to add the disabled attribute to a materializecss button for an anuglar app when the value of a particular input is either invalid or pristine, but there is a bug that causes the button to still be enabled when the input value is valid and all text is highlighted and deleted at once.

-

HTML:

```
<div input-field class="input-field col-xs-12 col-md-4">

    <input id="niNumberInput" name="niNumber" type="text" class="validate" pattern=".{9}" placeholder="{{niNumber}}" data-ng-model="niNumber">

    <label for="niNumberInput" data-error="National Insurance number must be 9 characters long">National Insurance Number</label>

</div>

<div input-field class="input-field col-xs-12 col-md-1">

    <button data-ng-click="verifyNINumber()" data-ng-disabled="mainDetailsForm.niNumber.$invalid || mainDetailsForm.niNumber.$pristine" class="btn button waves-effect"><span class="fa fa-search"></span>Verify</button>

</div>
```

-

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/6qswosh8/2/.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add `required` to your `input` element:

```
<input id="niNumberInput" name="niNumber" type="text" class="validate" 
pattern=".{9}" placeholder="{{niNumber}}" data-ng-model="niNumber" required>
```

Comment: I don't know why i didn't think of this

Answer (score 0):

You should add required attribute to niNumberInput.

By adding required attribute angular will check if the input field is left blank or not, if it is blank then it will be invalid

```
 <input id="niNumberInput" name="niNumberInput" ng-model="niNumberInput" type="text" class="validate" pattern=".{9}" placeholder="National Insurance Number" required>
```